# What should a table of presence/attendance be called precisely? (Schedule vs Attendance vs Timetable vs Time Sheet)

Tags: phrase-requests, british-english

I'm looking for a precise title to put on:

**A page on which people of a team indicate which days on a week they are present/working in the office.**

Looking for different terms, I've several options by non of which I am satisfied:

**Schedule:** This term suggests a meaningful series of timings or plans to achieve something. Its emphasizes the timing of the jobs not the people. From Merriam Webster's:

> 3 : PROGRAM
>
> especially : a procedural plan that indicates the time and sequence of each operation
>
> //finished on schedule

So, even adding prefixes to this term, can't describe what the document indicates.

**Timetable:** This one is very precisely on the timing of something specific. As used for timing of trains, I can accept this term to indicate the times that are agreed upon to coordinate daily or weekly events and their times but not people who are participating in them:

> 2 a : a schedule showing a planned order or sequence
>
> b : PROGRAM sense 3

**Time Sheet:** This one is precisely a tool to calculate how much time someone has spent on his work. This is specifically a record of past events not a plan for future. From Merriam Webster's:

> 1 : a sheet for summarizing hours worked by each worker during a pay period
>
> 2 : a sheet for recording the time of arrival and departure of workers and for recording the amount of time spent on each job

**Calendar:** A too generic term which carries no meaning on what it is to show. It suggests something long-term or a plan. This one has a long definition on Merriam Webster's Dictionary: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/calendar

**Attendance:** This one also suggests a record of the past. It has also too much emphasis on attending to something which is not the case in an office because it needs to be an event like a class. From Merriam Webster's:

> 2 a : the persons or number of persons attending something
>
> Attendance at the soccer games has been increasing.
>
> also : an account of persons attending
>
> The teacher took attendance [=made a record of who was present] before starting class.

There are combination of above words with **Sheet** and **Table** and also **Work Schedule** which is the best one I found but still unsatisfactory.

I'd be more than happy to hear ideas and arguments about the right term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another answer is **roster**

> noun: roster; plural noun: rosters
>
> ```
> 1.
> a list or plan showing turns of duty or leave for individuals or groups 
> in an organization.
> "next week's duty roster"
> "according to the roster, he was due to work today"
> a list of members of a team or organization, in particular of sports 
>      players available for team selection.
> "a cluster of outstanding players on the club's roster"
> ```
>
> verb: roster; 3rd person present: rosters; past tense: rostered; past
>   participle: rostered; gerund or present participle: rostering
>
> ```
> 1.
> place on or assign according to a duty roster.
> "the locomotive is rostered for service on Sunday"
> ```

Rota suggests that staff do a list of tasks **on rotation**, and both rota and roster suggests that tasks are *allocated* to people.

Please do not mix the two to make **rosta**.

For people indicating their future availability, or when they will be in the office, I would use **Calendar** especially as that's the term usually used for computerised diaries. *Please update your calendar to show when you'll be in the office for the next two weeks.* In some places people have **Office Hours** or **Office Times** when they will be working/available in the *office* and not out on visits or on leave, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for:

> [Rota](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rota)

*a list of things that have to be done and of the people who will do them*

Perhaps more suitable as it applies to your situation [Shift Rota](https://www.busybeemanager.com/shift-rota-why-and-how/)

Comment: Exactly  "Intra-partum care was provided by a rota of the seven midwives in the team and continuity of care was maximised where possible".

Comment: I guess I might invent the term "Presence Rota" to exactly match my purpose of the list.

Comment: I like rota as an answer. But I wonder is is less known in American English?